# Powershell - $args strips out the comma

Tags: string, powershell, command-line-arguments

I am writing a script to interface with 3rd party software.

They send string in the format:

```
sender-ip=10.10.10.10, primary site location=peachtree street, created by=jsmith
```

However, when the script executes

```
Write-host $args
```

This is the output

```
sender-ip=10.10.10.10 primary site location=peachtree street created by=jsmith
```

How do I preserve the original input string with the commas?

EDIT:

Below is snippit of code

```
$args = $args.ToString()
write-host '$args is' $args

foreach ($i in $args){
   $line_array+= $i.split(",")
   write-host '$line_array is' $line_array

}

foreach ($j in $line_array){
    $multi_array += ,@($j.split("="))
}

foreach ($k in $multi_array){
    $my_hash.add($k[0],$k[1])

}


$Sender_IP = $my_hash.Get_Item("sender-ip")
```

When I execute code with

```
script.ps1 sender-ip=10.10.10.10, primary site location=peachtree street, created by=jsmith
```

I get

```
$args is System.Object[]
$line_array is System.Object[]
$Sender_IP is
```

Answer (score 1):

It's interpreting that as multiple arguments.  You need to quote the whole thing so it knows it just one argument:

```
&{Write-Host $args} sender-ip=10.10.10.10, primary site location=peachtree street, created by=jsmith
&{Write-Host $args} 'sender 10.10.10.10, primary site location=peachtree street, created by=jsmith'

sender-ip=10.10.10.10 primary site location=peachtree street created by=jsmith
sender 10.10.10.10, primary site location=peachtree street, created by=jsmith
```

Comment: Either that, or he could re-join the arguments like this: `@{Write-Host ($args -join ', ')} sender-ip=...`

Comment: A third party program is sending in the arguments that is getting read into $args. I am trying to figure out out to cast the entire $args as a string. I tried $args = $args.ToString(), but that doesn't work .....

Comment: Also, the third party program will pass varying number of arguments, I must handle that too...

Answer (score 0):

When providing an arguments like `a b=c,d`, I found `$args` had the following array layout:

```
[
  "a",
  [
    "b=c",
    "d"
  ]
]
```

So to get the arguments back to having a comma, I'm using the following function:

```
function process_args {
  $newArgs=@()
  foreach ($arg in $args) {
    if ($arg -is [array]) {
      # collapse back any comma separated arguments to a string
      $newArgs += $arg -join ","
    } else {
      $newArgs += $arg
    }
  }
  return ,$newArgs
}

$args=(process_args @args)
```

Which leaves me with an array like:

```
[
  "a",
  "b=c,d"
]
```

This seems to have worked ok for me so far, but I don't know the details about powershell's CLI arg parsing so perhaps this is wrong... I'll report back if I find any edge cases.